# Can I exchange relative pronouns and articles in this way?

Tags: english-to-german, pronoun, relative-pronoun

> Wenn Sie Fragen haben, lassen Sie *es* mich wissen.

Why do we use *es* here? As *Fragen* is plural, why don't we use *sie*?

Whenever I don't want to repeat the noun, I either use its gender article as per the case or the corresponding pronoun for it. So, could the following be considered valid, too?

> Wenn Sie Fragen haben, lassen Sie *sie/die* mich wissen.

*Fragen* is an abstract word. Instead of *Fragen*, I could also use another object, e.g., *der Stift*:

> Das ist der Stift. Ich benutze *ihn/den* zum Schreiben.

Am I following the right path?

While reading I have noticed that some examples show two clauses using a relative pronoun and some examples show two different sentences using a relative pronoun.

Answer (score 11):

Note that

> Wenn Sie Fragen haben, lassen Sie *es* mich wissen.

does *not* mean

> If you have questions, let me know *them*.

but rather

> If you have questions, let me know *(that fact)*.

The fact that you might have questions is singular, thus *es* is used to relate to *that fact*.

Comment: You can use a parallel construction in English: "If you have questions, please let me know it." It probably has a different emphasis than the German version because the "it" is optional in English.

Comment: If you phrase it as “please let *it* be known” you have almost the same construction in English.

Comment: "Lassen Sie es mich wissen" for "Lassen Sie mich wissen dass sie Fragen haben"